# Send buffer as real image

Tags: node.js, image, buffer

Well I have a buffer inside mongoDB, and I want to send it like an image.

I tried many different things like `res.send(buffer)` or `fs.createReadStream(buffer).pipe(res)` and others. I really don't want to write this to real file in the server and then send it.

How can I send the buffer to the client without needing to write it to a file first?

Comment: Can you show us how you retrieve the image from MongoDB?

Comment: How did you finally implemented this ?

Comment: like in the answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could encode the buffer/image to base64 or whatever encoding you want and send that.

```
var encodedBuffer = buffer.toString('base64');

res.send(encodedBuffer);
```